# UIScrollView frame being automatically moved

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a UIScrollView with a UIView inside it. I've positioned this UIScrollView about halfway down the screen in storyboard editor. By default it appears where it's supposed to be, but doesn't respond to user interaction when I run my app. If I uncheck autolayout for my storyboard, interaction works, but the view is automatically moved to the top of the screen. Alternatively, I can leave the autolayout checked and insert the following code in my viewDidLoad:

```
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
noteContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

NSDictionary *viewsDictionary;
viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView, noteContainer);
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[noteContainer]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[noteContainer]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
```

In this case, the scroll view responds to interaction, but again is automatically moved to the top of the screen. Ridiculously frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround is to put the scrollview inside a generic UIView that's positioned where you want it.

Answer (score 1):

It goes to the top of the screen (and is the size of the screen) because that's what you told it to do in your constraints:

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
```

That constraint says make the scroll view have 0 distance to both the top and bottom of the screen. If you want it, say 150 points from the top, and to go all the way down to the bottom, you should have this:

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-150-[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
```